# What do you call a person who orders/hires someone to commit a crime (e.g. a murder)?

Tags: word-request

If someone pays someone else (through an intermediary or not) to illegally kill another person or commit some other crime, what noun should I use to describe the first individual? 'Customer'? 'Mandator'? 'Hirer'?

Comment: The term **proxy murder** is in [Wikipeida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_murder) but not in a dictionary that I can find, although [**proxy**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/proxy) is, of course. AFAIK in law, the person who hires a killer to do the deed is still a murderer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Criminologists have a name for a person who hires a hit man: instigator."

[(from an article in Atlantic Magazine)](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2019/07/hiring-a-hitman/590620/)

Of course, the root word "instigate" has softer meanings, too:
[AHD: 'instigate'](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=instigate)